# Cannot reference a DOM element in the JSF template from child view

Tags: javascript, html, jsf-2, xhtml, facelets

I'm using JSF templates and Primefaces. I don't seem to be able to reference a specific div in the main page from a sub view.

Template page **template.xhtml:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
     xmlns:comp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components"
     xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
  <h:head>
     <title><ui:insert name="title">Default title</ui:insert></title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
     <div id="header">Header</div>        
     <div id="content"><ui:insert name="content">Default content</ui:insert></div>
     <div id="footer">Footer</div>
  </h:body>
 </html>
```

client page **page.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:comp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components"
        xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">


    <ui:define name="content">
         <script type="text/javascript">
              $(window).load(function() {
                       alert($('header').html());
               });
         </script>

        <h1>New content here</h1>
        <p>Stuff</p>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The alert shows 'null'. I tried putting the script in different places inside the sub view but no luck. Any idea what why its not visible? Thanks.

Comment: Did you include jQuery script on that page?

Comment: I got rid of jQuery all together and used document.getElementById('..') still the same results.

Comment: Can you create example on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to select element with "header" in it's ID, so you need to use this:

```
$('#header')
```

If you wanted to select `<header>` element then you would use `$('header')` to select it.

Comment: Igor, I already tried that, but no luck. Even though I can see the element when I am displaying the page source on the browser.

Comment: Javascript exists, and that is why I am getting the alert dialog with result in it as (undefined).

Comment: Fiddler is showing the expected behavior:  http://jsfiddle.net/5DfUy/        but not on my local machine.

Comment: Try an `alert($)` and an `alert(jQuery('#header'))`, $ function is maybe bound to something else

Answer (score 0):

your original code had a separate header section, and then you also included a header section as a div in your body. the header html tag was removed and the ui tag moved to your div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
     xmlns:comp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components"
     xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
  <h:body>
     <div id="header"><ui:insert name="title">Default Title</ui:insert></div>        
     <div id="content"><ui:insert name="content">Default Content</ui:insert></div>
     <div id="footer">Footer</div>
  </h:body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What is this supposed to be?

Comment: the header on the top wouldn't show properly. since user was working w header it could've been something to help

Comment: An explanation should be in your answer. Without it, your answer is just a bunch of code, which makes it a low quality answer

Comment: Add an explanation to your answer please

Comment: He had `<head>` not header.

Comment: so i tested this online instead of local server, and missed the significance. was the issue resolved? i thought it had to do with the logic of adding the ui elements in the `<head>`, and then in the css, which apparently it may be or was not.